# CQ Workflow- Comment not transferring between participant with a process step in between

Tags: workflow, aem

When there is a process step between two participant steps, the comments is not passing between participants. My Workflow is like this-

ParticipantA ---> Process step X (ecma script)  ----> Process step Y (ecma script) -----> ParticipantB

When I add some comment at ParticipantA step it does not carry forward to ParticipantB. Seems OOB functionality has limitations on this.
As a workaround, I am trying to get it at "Process step X" and passing on to Process step Y. I am able to get it but not able to set it for next step.

Below is my code-

```
log.info("Noop process called for: " + workItem.getWorkflowData().getPayload());
var comment = workItem.getMetaDataMap().get("comment");
log.info("Comment in approval process-----------" + comment);

var workflowData = workItem.getWorkflowData();
if (workflowData.getPayloadType() == "JCR_PATH") {
    log.info("setting comment in meta data----------------");
    workflowData.getMetaDataMap().put("comment", comment);
}
```

Can you help on how to set comment for next step?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vivek

Answer (score 1):

You would need to actually store your comment within a workflow Metadata Map. [This](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/workflows/wf-extending.html#Persisting%20Data%20for%20Subsequent%20Workflow%20Steps/%22This%22) 
should help.

Once you have successfully stored your comment, you can access it later.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is a session change within the workflow. The `WorkflowData` instance will be newly set. You can easily check it in the debugger of your ide. You have to iterate over the HistoryItems as illustrated here:

```
final List<HistoryItem> history = workflowSession.getHistory(workItem.getWorkflow());
final List<String> comments = new ArrayList<>();

if (history.size() > 0) {
    HistoryItem current = history.get(history.size() - 1);

    do {
        comments.add(current.getComment());
        current = current.getPreviousHistoryItem();
    } while (current != null);
}
```

Comments are empty strings, if not set - if i'm not mistaken.